# What is the correct way of forcing https as well as redirecting just the root of the site to another https address

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, https

Here is my .htaccess file so far, server is running apache2.4.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://example2.org/ [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example1\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example2.org/ [L,R=301]
```

Forcing https works, but the redirect of root doesnt if I visit https://example1.org...I get the page at the address, it doesnt redirect to https://example2.org.

All other addresses such as https://example1.org/test shouldnt redirect.

Both addresses have got certs on them.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do with redirects:

```
Redirect permanent / https://example1.org/
```

You are using vhosts for both sites, aren't you?

Oh, you want to redirect only "/" and nothing else?. Maybe like this?

```
Redirect permanent ^/$ https://example1.org/
```

Or what are you trying to do?